# caused by: Cannot read property 'product_name' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I try to load a html form component in my angular2 app, it will not read a property on one part of the form.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in 
http://localhost:3000/app/material/material-new.component.html:15:7 
caused by: Cannot read property 'product_name' of undefined
```

I have another component that is identical bar the fields and does not encounter this problem when loaded. Components match and I am going mad about this.

Why does it not read that property of 'product_name' .

Heres the code.

Create Material

```
<div class="card container form-container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form (ngSubmit)="createMaterial(material)" #materialForm="ngForm"  >
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="label-text" for="product_name">Product 
           Name</label>
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
             id="product_name"
             placeholder="Product name"
             required
            name="product_name"
            #product_name='ngModel'
            [(ngModel)]="material.product_name">
           <div [hidden]="product_name.valid || product_name.pristine">


               Input product name
           </div>
    </div>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Material } from './material';
import { MaterialService } from './material.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'material-new',
 templateUrl: 'material-new.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['material-new.component.css'],
 providers: [ MaterialService ]
 })
  export class MaterialNewComponent {

material : Material;
submitted : boolean = false;


constructor(
  private materialService : MaterialService
) {}

createMaterial( material : Material) {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.materialService.createMaterial(material)
                    .subscribe(
                      data => { return true },
                      error => { console.log("error saving material")
                            return Observable.throw(error);
                          }
                    )
 }
```

}

Comment: Where do you define `material`?

Comment: material is not defined anywhere.

Comment: this is material : `export class Material {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public product_name?: string,
    public guk_name?: string,
    public roll_width_in?: number,
    public roll_length_m?: number,
    public factor?: number,
    public rounded_sale_price?: number,
    public list_price?: number,
    public cost_per_sqm?: number,
    public ink_per_sqm?: number,
    public supplier_discount?: number,
    public sell_per_sqm?: number
  ) {}
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You error points to `[(ngModel)]="material.product_name"`

Your material object is `undefined`, because you have not initialized it. So all you need to do, is to initialize your Object.

So change:

```
material : Material;
```

to

```
material : Material = <Material>{};
```

and it will no longer be `undefined`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Initialising the material object was the way to go. Cheers

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async` pipe to unwrap the `Observable` because it does the job of subscribing and unsubscribing automatically.

What you'll need to do:

TS Code:

```
material: Observable<Material>;

// In createMaterial
this.material = this.materialService.createMaterial(material);
```

Template:

```
[(ngModel)]="(material | async)?.product_name"
```

The `?` will check if `material | async` is undefined.

Comment: This crashed everything and gave me the longest error output in the console ever.